# Требуется учесть контекст перевода в статистике метки

Tags: дефект, локализация, описание-метки

В описании метки (например, [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)) есть блок статистики, который сейчас выглядит примерно так:

> [image: статистика]

Учитывая, что речь идёт о метке, требуется использовать женский род, т.е. произвести ряд замен:

- [создано](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265583?key=e2fa538867c3830a859a5b17ab24644b) → создана
- [просмотрен](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265329?key=55b371bdbea27963b0c9230e9f5d51e5) → просмотрена
- [обновлён](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/41732289?key=31b0a5858812ab3c82936710e2fa71b1) → обновлена

Дабы не поехал перевод этих одиночных слов в других местах, требуется предоставить возможность контекстно зависимого перевода в данном случае.

Причем для "обновлён" уже сейчас задан контекст `REFERS TO:lastQuestionActivity`, однако перевод используется в секции метки, что несколько странно.